# Magento 2.0.5. Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually

Tags: magento2, cache, backend

After installing magento 2.0.5 on a webserver (allinkl.com) i am recieving following error when i try to add come products in the backend: "Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually"

i already looked for solutions, but without any sucess.

what i did till now:

1) changed file.php ('cache_dir'=> '/var/tmp/')
2) var/cache/ and var/tmp/ both have chmod777 recursively

also i contacted the webhost regarding this failure (in my case i can not edit php.ini), they told me to try following:

1) create "temp" folder in magento root
2) edit .htaccess: add "php_value session.save_path /www/htdocs/xxxx/domain/temp/"

But this also did not work out.

Would be great if somebody could tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Linux dd25436 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

try this:

navigate to file: `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend.php`

edit the file (line 211) replace:

```
if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('/tmp')) {
    return '/tmp';
}
```

by this:

```
if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('var/tmp')) {
    return 'var/tmp';
}
```

only add var before `/tmp` do not add slash (/) before var.

tested on the 2.0.7 and working.

hope this will help.